# Python package classification and Python version

Tags: python, pypi, python-3.2

My module requires Python 3.2 or newer.

Should I only set the [Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=538) classification? Or should I set other versions (3.3 and 3.4 at the moment, more to follow) in addition to 3.2? It works in the newer versions.

How are the classification system supposed to be used? The categories are very ambiguous and lack definitions.

Comment: um. the linked page says "This page intentionally blank."

Answer (score 1):

I usually do not bother with point-release tags. Trove tags are there to assist with searching, but for a project that supports Python 3.x releases going back 4 and a half years, you just use the `Programming Language :: Python :: 3`, perhaps with `Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only` added.

I would use the point releases if the package explicitly does *not* support higher versions; if you don't support 3.4 or up, you could indicate so by tagging with `3.2` and `3.3`, for example.

If you do want to use point release tags anyway, then list *all* point releases you do support. You'll have to update for 3.5 if in future you start supporting that release. This is what the [`requests` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) does; they list all point releases that the library officially supports.

Comment: Should I still use `Programming Language :: Python :: 3 [:: Only]` when it only supports Python 3.2 and newer? Doesn’t 3 include 3.0 and 3.1 … .

Comment: @Aeyoun: yes, absolutely, to distinguish it from Python 2.

Comment: but that would not distinguish it from Python 3.1. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: @Aeyoun: it was never intended to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I only set the Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2 classification?

no.  If it supports newer, specify those versions, or don't specify point versions at all. (however, do specify major versions. 2/3)

I think you should "support" whichever versions you actively have under test.  so I put in whichever point versions I have under test in my `tox.ini`.